# Match on pair of enum when both are of the same kind

Tags: rust

I want to get rid of the repeated code here, and not have to list each enum kind:

```
use Geometry::*;
let geometry = match (&self.geometry, &other.geometry) {
    (Point(a), Point(b)) => Point(*a.interpolate(b, t)),
    (Curve(a), Curve(b)) => Curve(*a.interpolate(b, t)),
    (EPBox(a), EPBox(b)) => EPBox(*a.interpolate(b, t)),
    (_, _) => unimplemented!("Kinds not matching")
};
```

The types inside the kinds all implement the `Interpolate` trait which has the `interpolate` method:

```
enum Geometry {
    Point(Point),
    Curve(Curve),
    EPBox(EPBox)
}

trait Interpolate {
    fn interpolate(&self, other: &Self, t: f64) -> Box<Self> {
        // ...
    }
}

impl Interpolate for Point {}
impl Interpolate for Curve {}
impl Interpolate for EPBox {}
```

What I want to do is something like this:

```
let geometry = match (&self.geometry, &other.geometry) {
    (x(a), x(b)) => x(*a.interpolate(b, t)), // and check that a and b impls Interpolate
    (_, _) => unimplemented!("Kinds not matching")
};
```

Comment: This can be done with a proc macro on the enum definition.

Comment: Note: making a `Box<Self>`, and then unwrapping it (`*a`) seems redundant.

Comment: Thanks @ChayimFriedman, I will read up on procedural macros. You are correct @battlmonstr, switching the return type of `interpolate` to `Self where Self: Sized` works and gets rid of `Box<Self>`. My IDE says I need to use a Box though...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with the following solution, which is easy to extend with new Interpolate types:

```
macro_rules! geometries {
    ( $( $x:ident ),+ ) => {
        enum Geometry {
        $(
            $x($x),
        )*
        }
        fn interpolate_geometries(a: &Geometry, b: &Geometry, t: f64) -> Geometry {
            use Geometry::*;
            match (a, b) {
            $(
                ($x(a), $x(b)) => $x(a.interpolate(b, t)),
            )*
                _ => unimplemented!("Kinds not matching")
            }
        }
        $(
        impl Interpolate for $x {}
        )*
    };
}

geometries!(Point, Curve, EPBox);
```

Which make it possible to later do:

```
let geometry = interpolate_geometries(&self.geometry, &other.geometry, t);
```

Thanks for all answers and comments! Especially the one with the binop macro, which is quite similar to my solution. After reading up on macros (thanks to comments here) I came up with this solution.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure how many of these operations you want to implement, and how many enum variants you actually have. Depending on that, the best answer changes quite a bit, I think. If you really only have one operation (`interpolate`), and three variants: type it out, anything else will be a lot less simple and maintainable.

That being said, I might use

```
let geometry = binop!(match (&self.geometry, &other.geometry) {
    (a, b) => *a.interpolate(b, t)
});
```

based on

```
macro_rules! binop {
    (match ($av:expr, $bv:expr) { ($a:ident, $b:ident) => $op:expr }) => {{
        use Geometry::*;
        binop!($av, $bv, $a, $b, $op, Point, Curve, EPBox)
    }};
    ($av:expr, $bv:expr, $a:ident, $b:ident, $op:expr, $($var:path),*) => {
        match ($av, $bv) {
            $(($var($a), $var($b)) => $var($op),)*
            _ => unimplemented!("Kinds not matching")
        }
    };
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=1e07059e7dae70707349f6ba8ef9e4d2)

You'll have to list up the enum variants once. If you don't want that, you'll have to go for a proc macro. I think that would be overkill.

Comment: There will only be one operation (`interpolate`), but many (10-100) enum variants.

Comment: 100? Uff, ok, maybe you do want a proc macro. (Well, either that, or you have some normal macro generate both your enum and the massive match statement.)

Answer (score 1):

With your current code, you can't really do this. Checking if the enum variants are the same variant is fairly simple with the use of `core::mem::discriminant`, but you can't access the contained value without `match` or `if let` statements. What you can do is use type parameters for the variables and type IDs. This is a really tacky way to do things, and should be avoided really, but it works. I've given an example to show you how you could implement it

```rust
use std::any::Any;

trait SomeTrait {
    fn some_function(&self, other: Self) -> &Self;
}

#[derive(Clone)]
struct Var0 {
    eg: i64
}

#[derive(Clone)]
struct Var1 {
    other_eg: f64
}

fn check<T: 'static, B: 'static>(lhs: T, rhs: B) -> Option<T> {
    if lhs.type_id() == rhs.type_id() {
        Some(lhs.some_function(rhs))
    } else {
        None
    }
}

fn main() {
    let a = Var0{ eg: 2 };
    let b = Var0{ eg: 9 };
    let c = Var1 { other_eg: -3f64 };
    assert!(check(a.clone(), b).is_some());
    assert!(check(a, c).is_none());
}

impl SomeTrait for Var0 { /* ... */ }
impl SomeTrait for Var1 { /* ... */ }
```

Please note though: as I said before this is messy and pretty hacky and not very nice to read. If I were writing this I would use the `match` statement over this, but it's up to you what you do since this does require some reworking to implement. I'm also not sure if you can use different lifetimes for the `check` function other than `` `static `` which might be a problem.

Comment: This answer contradicts the comment above regarding using a proc macro. Do you not think my problem can be solved with a proc macro?

Comment: This cannot actually compile, can it? [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=da8352b932425fefd31284d1a2de2e4c) Problem is that `check` must require that T = B to call `some_function`, but if it does that, it becomes useless. `SomeTrait` (as well as `Interpolate`) isn't object safe, so you can't solve this with dynamic dispatch either. Am I missing something?

Comment: I haven't worked with macros a lot so I can't really comment on using one. And I'm pretty sure I compiled it locally. cannot remember how though sorry